# What is the correct way to compute information criteria for VAR(p) models?

Tags: time-series, aic, vector-autoregression

For a VAR($p$) model based on $k$ series, according to the 5th edition of Time Series Analysis by Box and Jenkins (page 517) the AIC is computed as:

$$AIC_p = \text{ln}(|\hat\Sigma_p|) +2pk^2/ N$$

where $|\hat\Sigma_p|$ is the determinant of the ML estimate of the residual covariance matrix.

However according to New introduction to multiple time series analysis by Luetkepohl, the AIC is computed as:

$$AIC_p = \text{ln}(\hat\sigma_p^2) +2pk^2/ N$$

where $\hat\sigma_p^2$ is now the sum of squared estimation residuals divided by the sample size, $N$. These do not *appear* to equate to the same thing.

So, who is correct? Why are they different? And, is $N$ actually the sample size or the number of residuals, which would be $N-p$ (due to the lag operation reducing the original data by $p$).

Comment: My two [radical] cents: from what I see, as long as the chosen measure reflect monotonously the amount of entropy in the resulting estimation, it doesn't matter which one you use, assuming you'll maintain it consistent. But I also feel there might be an asymptotic equivalence.